# Unable to click on the "Browse" button using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to click on the **"Browse"** button on the below webpage.

http://www.guru99.com/freelancing.html

I have written the below code but webdriver fails to find the Browse button element. Please help.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FileUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.guru99.com/freelancing.html");
        driver.findElement(By.id("theFile_link(Resume)")).click();
        //Below line execute the AutoIT script
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\FileUpload.exe");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

> **I'm Using:**
>
> **Firefox Version:** 49.0.1
>
> **Selenium Version:** Version 3.0.0-beta4
>
> **OS:** Win10 64 bit
>
> **Java:** 1.8

Comment: Update your ticket with exception log. Also let us know why you try to click that button and execute `AutoIT` script instead of just send path to file to `//input[@id="theFile_property(Resume)_1"]`

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML here as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form (and Browse button) is inside `<iframe>`, you need to switch to it first

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[src*='recruit'"])); //locate the iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code to click on browse:

```
//first switch to iframe as the browse button is inside the iframe.
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[src*='recruit'"])); 
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

//scroll into the browse button
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("theFile_link(Resume)"));
((JavascriptExecutor)   driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

//now click on browse button
element.click();
```

hope it will help you.